# Change an audio stream's volume by changing bytes directly

Tags: java, audio

For a peer-to-peer audio client, I need to have the ability to change the output volume to a desired level. In my case, the volume is a floating point number between zero and one.

I modify the audio stream this way:

```
void play(byte[] buf)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i += 2)
    {
        // sample size is 2 bytes, so convert to int and then back
        int data = ((buf[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (buf[i] & 0xFF);
        data = (int) (data * outputVolume);
        buf[i] = (byte) (data & 0xFF);
        buf[i + 1] = (byte) (data >> 8);
    }
    line.write(buf, 0, Math.min(buf.length, line.available()));
}
```

Now, when `outputVolume` is set to 0, the output is silent. When it is set to 1, it behaves normal and quality is fine (as it is not modified). But any numbers between 0 and 1 produce a horrible noise which is louder than the expected stream itself. At 0.5, the noise reaches it's loudest point.

I don't want to use the controls of the audio mixer itself (like gain control or volume control) because I had compatibility problems this way and later on, I want to modify the byte stream even more so I have to iterate through the stream anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio file - Manipulate volume given byte frames - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883820/audio-file-manipulate-volume-given-byte-frames-java)

Comment: What is the type of outputVolume? What is the type of line?

Comment: @xtractic I tried many ways to bit-shift the data, my problem seems to be another

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo outputVolume is a `float`. My line is a `SourceDataLine` with 16kHz sample rate, little-endian and 16 bits per sample

Comment: Can you give the displayed output of `byte[] buf = { 10, 11 }; play(buf); System.out.println(buf[0] + " ; " + buf[1]);`

Comment: Is it really little-endian unsigned 16 bits per sample?

Comment: Output for `outputVolume=0.5f` is `-123; 5`, which seems weird to me. Yes, the encoding is as mentioned but  I realized I am using a signed codec (because unsigned is not supported by my device), could this cause problems?

Comment: Yes, this is because your coded is signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the audio data is signed (because I think it would be pretty unusual to have unsigned 16-bit samples), there is a mistake in that code, because you also need to sign extend the sample.

You can remove the `& 0xFF` from the high byte which will let sign extension happen automatically:

```
int data = (buf[i + 1] << 8) | (buf[i] & 0xFF);
```

If for some reason you couldn't modify the and-shift-or expression, you could do sign extension like this:

```
int data = ((buf[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (buf[i] & 0xFF);
data = (data << 16) >> 16;
```

The result of the shifting expression is equivalent to this:

```
if (data > 32767)
    data -= 65536;
```

And this:

```
if ((i & 0x80_00) != 0)
    i |= 0xFF_FF_00_00;
```

(Those would also work.)

However, in your case you can just remove the `& 0xFF` from the high byte.

---

For a quick explanation, if you had some 16-bit sample like this (which is -1):

```
11111111_11111111
```

If you just convert to 32-bit without sign extending, you would get:

```
00000000_00000000_11111111_11111111
```

But that's 65536, not -1. Sign extension fills the upper bits with 1s if the MSB in the 16-bit value was set:

```
11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111
```

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks! Just removing the AND-operator was everything I needed to do.

Comment: Now, I got another question. I did the same for the input volume, but when lowering it, the sound gets kind of cut-off, like it is not a continous audio stream anymore. I would guess at a frequency around 5-10Hz. Do you have an idea?

Comment: A sample rate of 16kHz can only store frequencies up to 8kHz, so it would be normal for it to be cut off there. If there's some other problem, I'd have to see more of the code (preferably a [mcve], as described in the help center). I don't see any other problems in the code you posted.

Comment: Maybee cut-off was the wrong word for this. It sounds like the stream is interrupted at a hearable frequency. And the duty cycle depends on the volume. If the input volume is 1, it sound is continous. When set to 0, you hear nothing but a cracking (hard to explain) and when set to 0.5 for example, the duty cycle of the interrupts is around 50%. The code is equivalent to the code processing the output.

Comment: Sorry - I made a horrible mistake and skipped 8 bits in the stream, which have been reserved for a special purpose some time ago.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was going to suggest making an MCVE and posting a new question, but I'm glad you figured it then.